# Dynamic data-binding in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm building an AngularJS app and I have ran into an issue. I have been playing with the framework for a while and I have yet to see documentation for something like this or any examples. I'm not sure which path to go down, Directive, Module, or something that I haven't heard of yet...

**Problem:**

Basically my app allows the user to add objects, we will say spans for this example, that have certain attribute's that are editable: height and an associated label. Rather than every span have its own dedicated input fields for height and label manipulation I would like to use one set of input fields that are able to control all iterations of our span object.

So my approx. working code is something like this:

```
<span ng-repeat="widget in chart.object">
    <label>{{widget.label}}</label>
    <span id="obj-js" class="obj" style="height:{{widget.amt}}px"></span>
</span>
<button ng-click="addObject()" class="add">ADD</button>

<input type="text" class="builder-input" ng-model="chart.object[0]['label']"/>
<input type="range" class="slider" ng-model="chart.object[0]['amt']"/>
```

The above code will let users add new objects, but the UI is obviously hardcoded to the first object in the array.

**Desired Functionality:**

When a user clicks on an object it updates the value of the input's ng-model to bind to the object clicked. So if "object_2" is clicked the input's ng-model updates to sync with the object_2's value.  If the user clicks on "object_4" it updates the input's ng-model, you get the idea. Smart UI, essentially.

I've thought about writing a directive attribute called "sync" that could push the ng-model status to the bound UI. I've though about completely creating a new tag called `<object>` and construct these in the controller. And I've thought about using `ng-click="someFn()"` that updates the input fields. All of these are 'possibilities' that have their own pros and cons, but I thought before I either spin out on something or go down the wrong road I would ask the community.

Has anyone done this before (if so, examples)? If not, what would be the cleanest, AngularJS way to perform this? Cheers.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I don't think you need to use a custom directive specifically for this situation - although that may be helpful in your app once your controls are more involved.

Take as look at this possible solution, with a bit of formatting added:
http://jsfiddle.net/tLfYt/

I think the simplest way to solve this requires:
- Store 'selected' index in scope
- Bind ng-click to each repeated span, and use this to update the index.

From there, you can do exactly as you proposed: update the model on your inputs. This way of declarative thinking is something I love about Angular - your application can flow the way you would logically think about the problem.

In your controller:

```
$scope.selectedObjectIndex = null;

$scope.selectObject = function($index) {
    $scope.selectedObjectIndex = $index;
}
```

In your ng-repeat:

```
<span ng-repeat="widget in chart.object" ng-click="selectObject($index)">
```

Your inputs:

```
<input type="text" class="builder-input" ng-model="chart.object[selectedObjectIndex]['label']"/>
<input type="range" class="slider" ng-model="chart.object[selectedObjectIndex]['amt']"/>
```

Comment: Awesome. This is just what I was trying to do and exactly why I asked this question. Short and sweet.